# Why can't we make shrink/grow rays?

Tags: quantum-mechanics

In movies/etc. we see warping of objects that can change their size/etc.

I imagine that such a technological feature would help us do things like shrink or grow stuff, possibly other planets or ourselves -- or even something heavy/bulky we want away.

I imagine this would be easier with non-biological objects since they aren't as structurally complex.

Warping size seems to be something theoretically possible as the size of all matter can be shrunken or enlarged to a certain point and still remain. For example, you can shrink wood as long as its cells still work. So I don't see any reason why people aren't working on actual grow/shrink rays/etc.

These devices could make the moon smaller so that it won't affect tides; or maybe make us bigger.

Who wouldn't want to explore these possibilities? After all, this is more possible than time travel.

Here's some more stuff since I educated myself in the last few minutes:

You cannot shrink atoms, but you can shrink larger compounds into their basest equivalents of atoms to a point where they still will function on a higher-level. This rationale is a debate over subjects such as mass and volume. Volume is how much space -- mass is how much weight. If we reduce object volume while still keeping necessary molecular integrity, we can shrink and grow objects without affecting atomic structure or other such criteria. Overall this seems 100% possible.

Atoms are so tiny that we often don't even realize how small they are. The important concerns scientists probably have are things like, "How do we manage to shrink/enlarge something without destroying it normal compound and makeup?"

I feel ya. I have looked at quarks, and it appears there're theories that postulate that quarks actually come and go in and out of existence. I believe it's therefore possible for objects to grow and shrink by quantum-depreciation -- that is, passing along parts of chemical compound chains into quark-like equivalents that quickly disseminate size while still quickly bringing it back.

Comment: This question is too broad, and I am afraid off-topic. Apart from that, how do you make everything consist of only (say) half of as was before? Suppose a stick of timber consists of 1 million cells, then you wish to reduce it only to 500 thousand cells, or otherwise every cell must be half of as was before. Either case, I don't see it obvious that it is surely possible.

Comment: The scientists mostly work for the government. I think a non-government scientist who thinks outside of the bureaucracy can do this. Most scientists are not open-minded, so they'll be lapdogs for the feds. Of course the feds don't want shrink rays because then you can shrink their already tiny gonads.

Comment: Also, this question is not too broad. I am asking if shrink/grow rays are possible. I even put effort into understanding what I'm spewing here. I don't think this question is as broad as you feel it is.

Comment: Go to Skeptics SE, please....

Comment: This site is a question for mainstream physics, so you are off topic, since you are asking a science fiction question, i.e. a question not based on mainstream known repeatable physics processes. No , there can be no shrink ray the way you describe . sorry, but I wil suggest closing . Take it to science fiction site.

Comment: It may be popular due to science fiction, but the underlying aspects of it are purely related to Physics.

Comment: It is not 100% off-topic; maybe 23.8%.

Comment: @ShelfDancer  The "ray " concept is 100% off mainstream. It is like "Alice in wonderland" who grows by eating the cake that said "eat me", and shrinks through a fan she has picked up https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alice%27s_Adventures_in_Wonderland#Plot . The physics part is whether with a different mix of postulated constants due to measurements, a stable configaration of chemistry etc could exist.

Comment: Please don't be discouraged; we are all well meaning and we all cherish science fiction. World building is suitable, if you can rephrase in proper way. Otherwise, you may focus on more specific part, such as: is it possible to shrink a cell for half for it still to function properly? Ask one aspect a time.

Answer (score 3):

Because things are made up of atoms and the size of atoms is determined by electrodynamics, meaning that the only way to make something half-size is to somehow discard 87.5% of its atoms and hope that nothing important went missing. (The proportion I just cited $p$ of atoms removed relates to the scale factor $s = 1/2$ as $p = 1-s^3$ because we're in 3D space.) If you have a typically noisy process then things presumably will go missing quite readily; it depends on the material whether this has a huge effect or not. For crystal structures, for example, the only worry is the noise; if you could eliminate the atoms perfectly uniformly you could probably preserve a smaller crystal lattice. For a bundle of carbon nanotubes, probably they will individually lose their nanotube structure under any reasonable sampling of the carbon atoms. For the proteins that make up a living being, all of them will refold into nonfunctional forms, killing the organism.

Comment: I don't believe this answer is going to convince me that the process is impossible.

Comment: I dance for a living, so I know that things can shrink whether you want them to or not.

Comment: I mean, are you proposing removing enough water molecules that you mummify a person? Because that will certainly shrink them a little bit, though I doubt you'll get a full factor of 2 shrinkage. Otherwise, I mean, it's well known that water is a highly incompressible fluid, most solids are pretty incompressible, gases are usually modeled as incompressible unless you travel through them near their speed of sound. Conformal changes as happen in clothing can sometimes make something which once was stretched out become smaller, but those will simply not help shrink a steel bar or a liter of blood.

Comment: Sounds like you're only considering this on the quantum level.

Comment: @ShelfDancer The underlying frame of nature is quantum mechanical,  that is the mainstream physics  conclusion from innumerable measurements and observations.

Comment: Doesn't prove that you can't truncate or expand molecular structures.

Comment: I mean, it does, actually. Bond lengths are a prediction of physical chemistry, which is applied quantum mechanics.

Comment: So you are saying that shrink/grow rays are never possible to happens?

Comment: A troller in stackexchange? Bad times indeed, really bad times.....